# VPC private server can't access web via gateway server

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, proxy-server, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up a gateway server for a private server using DigitalOcean's VPC service (I’ll refer to the two servers as GW (gateway) and BE (backend) for brevity’s sake). I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/vpc/resources/droplet-as-gateway/) almost to the letter, but after removing the public IP from the netplan file in the last step of the BE configuration guide, the BE cannot access the internet at all. For whatever reason it seems the BE is not successfully using the GW as a proxy to access the web. Whenever I try to ping a site (i.e. google.com) from the BE it gives me the error: “Temporary failure in name resolution.” Both servers are running Ubuntu 18.04.

I know some people have had trouble getting this configuration to work because UFW was blocking routing requests on the GW server, but the results are the same for me even if I disable UFW on both servers. I know the GW and BE are connected in the network because I can ping the BE via its private IP from the GW, and vice versa. Any help with why this isn’t working would be greatly appreciated-- I don’t even know how to troubleshoot where in the rerouting process the problem is occurring, so tips in that vein would be useful as well.

ETA: `ip r` on the BE server returns (I've omitted the specific ip's for privacy sake):

```
default via [GW priv ip] dev eth1 proto static
10.xx.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.xx.0.xx
10.xxx.0.0/16 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src [BE priv IP]
159.xxx.xxx.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src [BE public IP]
169.254.169.254 via [BE gateway IP] dev eth0
```

ETA2: So if anyone is curious, it turns out that uhh... the problem was I had made a typo when entering an IP address in one of the commands, and failed to notice the several times I checked the rule that had been created. Moral of the story is don't be dumb like me.

Comment: Add `ip r` output from the BE. Also does `ping` or so work for (public) IPs (e.g. `8.8.8.8`) instead of domain names?

Comment: @Tom I've added the routing info above. Pinging 8.8.8.8 did at least seem to send requests, but returned 0 received/100% packet loss.

Comment: Hmm, what about `ip r` on the GW? You mentioned that BE can reach GW, do you mean with `[GW priv ip]`? Make sure no firewall on GW blocks forwarding traffics as well (`iptables-save`, `nft list ruleset`), with a rule or default policy.